# Is there a DateTime setting in .NET which automatically sets format to 12 or 24 hour clock based on culture?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, time, datetime-format

Basically the question says it all: I want to be able to set a format of date and time except the 12/24 clock setting which should be taken from culture settings.

So for instance for en-US I want to have `h:mm tt` (3:34 PM) and for fr-FR `H:mm` (15:34)

Should I just manually code:

```
string format = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortTimePattern.Contains("tt") ? "h:mm tt" : "H:mm"
```

or is there a more elegant way?

There is a similar question here: [.net Culture specific 12/24 hour formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8086890/1813219) but the author wants to force AM/PM clock but leave the time/date local format intact which is the opposite of my question.

Comment: Is there any help here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tostring?view=netcore-3.1#System_DateTime_ToString_System_String_System_IFormatProvider_ - you pass the culture as a parameter to the ToString method - see "t Format Specifier" for your particular example

Comment: If you find a more elegant way, I'd be interested! What we ended up doing (some years ago, so maybe things have changed) is exactly what you are doing - check for the "tt" specifier in the short time patten.

Comment: Set [CurrentCulture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.currentculture) and [CurrentUICulture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.currentuiculture) properties to desired culture.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different ways to deal with this:

- You can do what you suggested, testing for the `tt` existence:

  ```
  cultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.ShortTimePattern.Contains("tt")
  ```
- Similarly, you can test if the AM or PM designator strings are present.  (This is slightly more reliable, I think.)

  ```
  String.IsNullOrEmpty(cultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.PMDesignator)
  ```
- You could take the `ShortTimePattern` and replace any tokens you want to modify or remove.
- You could just use the `ShortTimePattern` as-is, and trust the format is suitable for the user.